# How can I make an array of a HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Here is my DOM:

```
...
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><img src="../first"></td>
        <td>John</td>
    <\tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><img src="../second"></td>
        <td>Peter</td>
    <\tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
...
```

Now I want to make this array: *(to pass it to the server side and make a .CSV export of it)*

```
var arr = array();
arr = array(array(1,'../first','John'),array(2,'../second','Peter'));
```

How can I make array above from the DOM ?

---

**Note:** I use jquery, So I can get the `src` attribute by using this:

```
$('img').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested yet. Basically you need to iterate through all `<tr>` and get each values.

BTW, `array` should be `Array`.

```
var arr = Array();
$('table tr').each(function(index) {
    var id = $(this).children()[0].innerText;
    var imageSrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    var name = $(this).children()[2].innerText;
    arr.push_back(Array(id, imageSrc, name));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this .create `array` of  each `tr` and then push with main array

```js
var res = []

var a = $('tbody tr')
a.each(function(a, b) {
  a = [];
  a[0] = $(this).children('td').eq(0).text();
  a[1] = $(this).children('td').eq(1).children('img').attr('src');
  a[2] = $(this).children('td').eq(2).text();
  res.push(a);
})
console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><img src="../first"></td>
      <td>John</td>
      <tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td><img src="../second"></td>
          <td>Peter</td>
          <\tr>
  <\tbody>
<\table>
```

Comment: typo : near tr tag    <\tr>

Answer (score 0):

You can return array using `map()` and `get()`.

```js
var array = $('tr').map(function() {
  return [$(this).find('td').map(function(i) {
    return i == 1 ? $(this).find('img').attr('src') : $(this).text()
  }).get()]
}).get()

console.log(array)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><img src="../first"></td>
      <td>John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><img src="../second"></td>
      <td>Peter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add an `id` to your `table`, to make sure that you do not accidentally send rows from other `table` to the server:

```
<table id="request-rows">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><img src="../first"></td>
        <td>John</td>
    <\tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><img src="../second"></td>
        <td>Peter</td>
    <\tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then build your array like this:

```
var arr = [];
$("#request-rows tr").each(function() {
    var tds = $(this).find("td");
    var newElement = [$(td[0]).text(), $(td[1]).find("img").attr("src")];
    arr.push(newElement);
});
//Do something with arr
```